# How do we deal with ArcTan (or other inverse functions) of undefined values?

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

When converting coordinates from rectangular to cylindrical, to spherical, etc. we will eventually come across having to use $ArcTan(y/x)$, and/or $ArcCos(z/\rho)$ to derive $\theta$ and/or $\phi$. However, sometimes the $x$ coordinate used in $ArcTan(y/x)$ may very well be $0$, which makes the fraction undefined.  How do we retrieve the angle we need in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

When converting from rectangular to cylindrical, the statement that $\theta=\arctan \frac yx$ is a bit sloppy.  You need to start with if $x=0, \theta = \pm \frac \pi 2$ depending on the sign of $y$ because the arctangent never returns $\pm \frac \pi 2$.  Then you can use the arctangent formula, but you may have to add $\pi$ depending on the quadrant.  Computer languages have an atan2 function that takes care of all that for you.  The conversion to spherical is similar.

Comment: I too don't understand why $arctan(0/0)$ is undefined as opposed to indeterminate [1]. [2] states ``In mathematics, division by zero is division where the divisor (denominator) is zero. Such a division can be formally expressed as a/0 where a is the dividend (numerator). In ordinary arithmetic, the expression has no meaning, as there is no number which, multiplied by 0, gives a (**assuming** $a\neq 0$), and so division by zero is undefined.'' Can someone clarify this point?  *BIBLIOGRAPHY*   [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form. [2]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Comment: @MichaelLevy:  $0/0$ is undefined regardless of the fact that it is the argument of an arctangent.  What angle would you like returned for the point $(0,0)$.  Indeterminate is used in the case of limits, where the limit of the numerator and denominator are both zero, but here we have hard values of $0$.  The sense is that indeterminate may have a reasonable value but you have to work harder

Comment: (1) My intuition is as follows: since $\rho$ is zero, the angle formed may as well be isotropic (i.e., taking any angle with equal probability). Hence, the angle is indeterminate, but not undefined. (2) For completeness sake, I amend my quote from [2]. The very next line of [2] reads "Since any number multiplied by zero is zero, the expression 0/0 is also undefined."

Answer (score 0):

if
$x = \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi\\y = \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\z = \rho\cos\phi$

then $\frac {y}{x} = \tan \theta$ and $\arctan \frac{y}{x} = \arctan (\tan\theta) = \theta$ if $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac {\pi}{2})$

If $\theta$ is not in the correct interval you will need to add (or subtract) some multiple of $\pi$

If $x=0$ then $\arctan \frac{y}{x}$ is undefined, but you may be able to find a limit as x approaches 0.